# Reflection: How to access private method in private inner class, that is in different package than caller class

Tags: java, reflection, java-17

I am having trouble in accessing private method in private inner class that resides in different package than caller class:

```java
package reflectiontest.sompackage;

import reflectiontest.Interface;

public class Outer {
    private class Inner implements Interface {
        public int get() {
            return 4;
        }
    }

    public Interface getInner() {
        return new Inner();
    }
}
```

```java
package reflectiontest;

public interface Interface {
    int get();
}
```

```java
package reflectiontest;

import reflectiontest.sompackage.Outer;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Outer outer = new Outer();
        Interface inner = outer.getInner();

        System.out.println(inner.get());

        Method get = inner.getClass().getMethod("get");
        System.out.println(get.invoke(inner));
    }
}
```

Log after running:

```java
4
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class reflectiontest.Main cannot access a member of class reflectiontest.sompackage.Outer$Inner with modifiers "public"
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:394)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:709)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
    at reflectiontest.Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

During debugging i got to the point in `Reflection.verifyMemberAccess()` fails at this point:

```java
        if (!Modifier.isPublic(getClassAccessFlags(memberClass))) {
            isSameClassPackage = isSameClassPackage(currentClass, memberClass);
            gotIsSameClassPackage = true;
            if (!isSameClassPackage) {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

The one option is to create a simple caller class inside the same package as Inner, but this seems a workaround.

Any other ideas on how to get it to work?

Comment: Does `get.setAccessible(true)` right before `get.invoke` not work? That said, you really should not do that. If `Inner` does not implement a public interface that exposes `get`, `get` is an implementation detail which YOU SHOULD NOT CALL.

Comment: Why do you need Reflection? Just call `inner.get()`. If you think, you really have make the call via Reflection, use `Interface.class.getMethod("get")`. Or in general terms, don’t use `getClass()`.

Comment: Nope - the method is public, so accessible. That is part of springframework. I do not have the power to change how it looks like :) And yet it does - Inner implements public interface (called Interface here). But still Inner is private.

Comment: @Holger, because this code is just a example - in project i am using Proxy so i need to call using reflection (or to rewrite a huge chunk od legacy code). I will try with the interface though.

Comment: As said in [the other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76521450/?noredirect=1#comment134921446_76521538), a proxy gets the right `Method` object (having the interface or `java.lang.Object` as declaring class) which can be used to invoke the method on a delegate if it implements the same interface. If the delegate implements a different interface, you need to use `Interface.class` as shown above.

Comment: @Holger, you are right with the `Interface.class` thing. Write an answer and i will confirm it. Thanks

Comment: Don't use `getClass().getMethod(...)`. If you know it is an `Inner`, use `Inner.class`. If you did obtain the value using reflection, consider using `m1.getReturnType().getMethod(...)`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn, but `Inner` is `private`. I cannot access it like that. Best way is as @Holger mentioned.

Comment: Yeah. Use the most specific public superclass/interface - in this case `Interface.class`. Or use the return type of `getInner()` - which is `Interface.class` (but in some cases easier to get with `Method.getReturnType()`).

Answer (score 0):

From the docs (emphasis is mine):

> An IllegalAccessException is thrown when an application **tries to reflectively** create an instance (other than an array), set or get a field, or **invoke a method**, but the currently executing method **does not have access to the definition** of the specified class, field, method or constructor.

Thus as you obviously can't access this private class by naming it, the exception is thrown. You can either use `get.setAccessible(true)` or reflect on the  `Interface` that is accessible to you:

```
Outer outer = new Outer();
Interface inner = outer.getInner();

System.out.println(inner.get());

Method get = Interface.class.getMethod("get"); // Interface is accessible...
System.out.println(get.invoke(inner));
```

It works because `invoke` uses the dynamic dispatch.

Answer (score -1):

First of all: reflections are evil, get rid of it ;) then: try `get.setAccessible(true)`

Comment: I am using a Proxy for delegating. I must use it ;) Tried `setAccessible()` with ot luck - it works for methods - and in this case method is already public.

Comment: A proxy gets the right `Method` object as argument. Just use that.

Comment: Yeap but then in `InvocationHandler` you need to use it. And if caller (Main or InvocationHandler implementation) is in different package than Inner class (or Outer) you get an error.